# Script that search for a string in the ouptput of a command

Tags: linux, script

This may sound a bit complicated but I do not see any other way.

I want to create a script that will check after running the command 'cli ha'

to search if a certain line contains a string = 'Active' , if it finds it then it will launch an action or so,

Any ideas?

Comment: How about trying `SED`, `GREP` utlities

Comment: I just tried grep  with the below :

`if (cli ha | grep -q '172.16.1.1\s*Active')
then
  echo "Yes"
else
 echo "Nope"
fi`

it worked fine! thank you

Comment: Something like this? `if [[ $(cli ha | grep 'Active') == 'Active' ]] ; then echo "good" ; fi`